# Unsupported operands for range and float, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to pass a range of numbers to a function and have that function then give me an array of numbers back. This is my code and the error I've received. 
I'm brand new to python, so this might be a silly question. 
[image: This is my snippet of code]

Comment: You cannot perform mathematical operations on a `range()` as a whole. Nor on Python's standard array (list) objects. It's not supported. numpy matrix objects do support those operations, in some form (I'm not sure about the syntax). You may want to use those instead.

Comment: So if I then make my range t=np.array([1,5]) and then pass that to my function, it tells me that it can only convert length-1 arrays to scalar?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, the binary `-` operator needs to numbers and can't work with a iterable.

Use **list comprehension** to achieve this behaviour:

```
V_esc = [232+15*math.cos((2*math.pi)*(t-152.5/365.25)) for t in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`t` is a range type. Python is telling you that you can't subtract a `range` and a float. In other words, `t-152.5` is what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to keep in mind here is that 
`t = range(5)` returns an iterable object. That is, it basically contains the ability to return numbers from 0 to 4.

You can verify this by the following piece of code:

```
for i in t:
    print(i)    
0
1
2
3
4
```

So you cannot basically perform any binary operation on two objects that are heterogenous. The operator '+' acts as addition for numeric types and for lists, they act as append operator. 
Also called Dynamic Typing Interlude in python. (In simple words, run time polymorphism.)

So in your case you have to iterate through the entire range one by one.

By old-school method:

```
V_esc = []
for i in t:
    V_esc.append(232 + 15*math.cos((2*math.pi) * (i-152.5/365.25)))


V_esc
Out[25]: 
[218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.9694886591047]
```

If you want to show off your python list comprehension skills:

```
t = range(5)
V_esc = [232 + 15*math.cos((2*math.pi) * (i-152.5/365.25)) for i in t]

V_esc
Out[21]: 
[218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.9694886591047]
```

Or even better:

```
V_esc = [232+15*math.cos((2*math.pi)*(t-152.5/365.25)) for t in range(5)]

V_esc
Out[23]: 
[218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.96948865910474,
 218.9694886591047]
```